# Why does paired columns with the same name from a df get changed after being imported on Python using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, debugging, python-import

I realized of something very weird today, I have a .csv file which contains a `df` that is displayed as shown below when open with `Excel`:

[image]

One could think after executing the following code on `Python3x`:

```
import pandas as pd
metadata_file_path = r'C:\Users\ResetStoreX\Pictures\Metadata.csv'

df_metadata = pd.read_csv(metadata_file_path, index_col=0)
print(df_metadata)
```

**The expected output should be this one down below**:

```
            0     0    1    1      2          2         3        3     4    4      5    5         
0  Background Ocean Body Crab Colour Dark green Eyes type Antennae Claws None Spikes None            
1  Background Ocean Body Crab Colour Dark green Eyes type Antennae Claws None Spikes Brown     
2  Background Ocean Body Crab Colour Dark green Eyes type Antennae Claws None Spikes Green    
3  Background Ocean Body Crab Colour Dark green Eyes type Antennae Claws None Spikes Purple    
4  Background Ocean Body Crab Colour Dark green Eyes type Antennae Claws None Spikes Sand
```

**However, it ends up being this one instead**:

```
            0   0.1    1  1.1      2        2.1         3      3.1     4  4.1      5   5.1         
0  Background Ocean Body Crab Colour Dark green Eyes type Antennae Claws None Spikes None            
1  Background Ocean Body Crab Colour Dark green Eyes type Antennae Claws None Spikes Brown     
2  Background Ocean Body Crab Colour Dark green Eyes type Antennae Claws None Spikes Green    
3  Background Ocean Body Crab Colour Dark green Eyes type Antennae Claws None Spikes Purple    
4  Background Ocean Body Crab Colour Dark green Eyes type Antennae Claws None Spikes Sand
```

As can be seen, the columns with the same name were modified by Pandas (or Python) when imported, so it was added `0.1` to the next column with the same name of the previous one.

I don't understand why this happens, and if possible, I would like to know a way of preventing this unexpected modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas `read_*` methods always prevent duplicated columns names, because is problem with selecting.

If use `df[0]` it select both columns, not one.

---

For original columns names is possible use:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.').str[0].astype(int)
```

Another idea is used first values before `.` for grouping without change columns names:

```
row = 0
d = {x.iat[0]: x.iat[1] for name, x in df.iloc[row].groupby(lambda x: x.split('.')[0], level=0)}
```

Comment: Amazing sir, thanks again for solving my issue, I appreciate that even more, after mixing `df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.').str[0].astype(int)` with `row = 0` and `d = {x.iat[0]: x.iat[1] for name, x in df.iloc[row].groupby(lambda x: x.split('.')[0], level=0)}` it threw no errors  I hope one day to get as much knowledge as you about Pandas.